# How to debug regular expressions in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, regex

I am new to both JavaScript and Regular Expression. I have a simple task to replace a series of <%whatever%> into (whatever) within the web page. Somehow regExp works in certain conditions only.

I am not sure if I've got the Expression wrong or the way I try to access document.body.HTML wrong. Please note the "works" and "not working" remarks within the code.

```
<html>
<head>
  <script>
  </script>
</head>
<body>
  Hello, my items are <%abc%>, <%efg%>, <%hik%><p/>
  <p/>
</body>
<script>
var Transform = function() {
    var regExp = /<%\^?\w+?\.?\w+?%>/gi;
    document.body.innerHTML = document.body.innerHTML.replace(/Hello/g,"Hi"); //works
    document.body.innerHTML = document.body.innerHTML.replace(/my/g,"your"); //works
    document.body.innerHTML = document.body.innerHTML.replace(/\<%/g,"("); //not working
    document.body.innerHTML = document.body.innerHTML.replace(/%\>/g,")"); //not working
    return;
}
teststr="<%abc%>";
teststr=teststr.replace(/\<%/g,"(");
teststr=teststr.replace(/%\>/g,")"); //works show as (abc)
console.log(teststr)
Transform();
</script>
</html>
```

Comment: @siam: no, `%` isn't a regex special character. (`<` and `>` too)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a number of problems with the code:

- `<%abc%>` (and the other ones) are converted to text, because they are illegal HTML tags. So when you look at `document.body.innerHTML`, you see things like `&lt;%abc%&gt;` instead. You can get around this by using `.innerText` insetad of `.innerHTML`, depending on the specifics of what you need to do.
- Anything after the opening `<body>` tag will be shoved into the body tag. So your script is also part of `.innerHTML`. To fix this, you could add your script in the `<head>` and set `window.onload` to run your code after the body has been set up. Alternatively you could put your content in a `<div>` within the body and do your replace on that.
- You are getting `.innerHTML` 4 times, which could cause problems later down the line. You could instead operate on the same string and set `.innerHTML` once.

```html
<html>
<head>
  <script>
  console.clear()
var Transform = function() {
    var regExp = /<%\^?\w+?\.?\w+?%>/gi;
    document.body.innerHTML = document.body.innerHTML
      .replace(/Hello/g,"Hi") //works
      .replace(/my/g,"your") //works
      .replace(/&lt;%/g,"(") //now working!!
      .replace(/%&gt;/g,")"); //now working!!
    return;
}

    window.onload = Transform;
  </script>
</head>
<body>
  Hello, my items are <%abc%>, <%efg%>, <%hik%><p/>
  <p/>
</body>
</html>
```

If something doesn't work, start from the point closest to the part not working and step backwards through the code. Log things to the console (`console.log`) to make sure values are as you expect. Make sure your code is running in the correct order, log values *after* you've logged them--things like that.

Comment: Thanks. I also discover that the key is to use &gt; and &lt; instead of < and >. As you said, it has to do that HTML contents are encoded instead of straight text, which is in the case of text stored in the variable.

Answer (score 0):

That happens because when we talk about innerHTML, browser interprets < as &lt; and > as &gt;

So you need to modify your regular expression as in following demo.

```js
var teststr = document.body.innerHTML;
teststr = teststr.replace(/&lt;%/g,"(");
teststr = teststr.replace(/%&gt;/g,")");
console.log(teststr);
```

```html
<body>
  Hello, my items are <%abc%>, <%efg%>, <%hik%>
</body>
```

**Important** : Getting innerHTML of body will also include your script (if you've noticed that script is printing in console).
So better is that you should avoid that and use querySelectors instead or put script in `<head>` section.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you want

```js
const data = `<p></p><% <b>here is some text</b> %>
  <% you probably want to do something more %>
  <% x = 2 * 2 ?%>` // inner html

const parse = (data) => data.replace(/<(?:%|&lt;)((?:\n|.)*?)(?:%|&gt;)>/g, data => {
  // calc value to replace here
  return data
})

// here is just replacement
const parse2 = (data) => data.replace(/<(?:%|&lt;)((?:\n|.)*?)(?:%|&gt;)>/g, '$1')

console.log(parse2(data))
```